# How to do postal addresses fuzzy matching?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, fuzzy

I would like to know how to match postal addresses when their format differ or when one of them is mispelled.

So far I've found different solutions but I think that they are quite old and not very efficient. I'm sure some better methods exist, so if you have references for me to read, I'm sure it is a subject that may interest several persons.

The solution I found (examples are in R) :

- Levenshtein distance, which equals the number of characters you have to insert, delete or change to transform one word into another.

  `agrep("acusait", c("accusait", "abusait"), max = 2, value = TRUE)`
  `## [1] "accusait" "abusait"`
- The comparison of phonemes

  `library(RecordLinkage)`
  `soundex(x<-c('accusait','acusait','abusait'))`
  `## [1] "A223" "A223" "A123"`
- The use of a spelling corrector [(eventually a bayesian one like Peter Norvig's)](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), but not very efficient on address I guess.
- I thought about using the suggestions of Google suggest, but likewise, it is not very efficient on personal postal addresses.
- You can imagine using a machine learning supervised approach but you need to have stored the mispelled requests of users to do so which is not an option for me.

Comment: It would be good to know the end use of the matching. Such as what sort of data you are searching, pure user input or authoritative data source?

Comment: @StephenKeable I have postal addresses from different sources, that I want to use as a key for merging database. Imagine for example a French address like "62 bvd Col Prevost", you would like to match it with "62 boulevard Colonel de Prevot", for example.

Comment: Ok, if possible I'd recommend cleansing the data against the national postal database, then you would have items to match far easier. Ideally you would do this at the point of data capture, but I imagine you have a body of data already. Otherwise you could create a dictionary of synonyms for different road types (ave, rd, st, bvl, rue etc)